# POST Variables to ADF Application

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, oracle-adf

I have an external application that needs to send POST data to a ADF Faces jspx page, then logic inside the ADF application will take over.

Everytime i try to access the POST variables in the request scope, they are null. Meanwhile GET variables are still accessible, but I can't send data over GET variables for security reasons.

Any way on how to do this?

Thank you,

Gavin

Comment: can you provide us some code on how you try to get the POST vars?

Comment: I tried multiple things: request.getParameter("cal_user") in the JSPX (JSP Expression). Created managed bean for my AfterPhase and BeforePhase with the following logic:         

HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        String value = request.getParameter("cal_user");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1) I would suggest this one the most :
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/passing_parameters_to_adf_appl

2) Make a java class which extends HttpServlet so you can easily catch your params.

Comment: Thanks! I created an HTTP Servlet and catched my POST data. Worked perfectly. I'll post my solution to the end of my question later today or tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be safe to use a thread-local to store the incoming request as part of a listener.

```
package my.pkg.http.listener;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class Request implements ServletRequestListener {
  private static final ThreadLocal<ServletRequest> requests = new ThreadLocal<ServletRequest>();

  public void requestInitialized( ServletRequestEvent event ) {
    requests.set( event.getServletRequest() );
  }

  public void requestDestroyed( ServletRequestEvent event ) {
    requests.remove();
  }

  public static HttpServletRequest currentRequest() {
    return ( HttpServletRequest ) requests.get();
  }
}
```

You would need to alter the web.xml to include the listener as follows:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>my.pkg.http.listener.Request</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then in theory you can simply access the request using `Request.currentRequest()`. If the request is still intact, the post variables should be available.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the input, this looks like a really good solution for when i need to continually send POST data. However, since i am only transferring this data through one http request, I created a HTTP Servlet. I'm going to try this out anyway, since i'm learning ADF and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: You could always add a filtering mechanism :)